# disable ordering inside $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a session variable which looks like this when printed:

```
Array
(
    [cart_4] => 1
    [cart_8] => 1
    [cart_9] => 2
    [cart_18] => 1
)
```

The thing is, i did not add stuff to it in that order, but because of the keys it always has that order. So is it possible to keep the items inside the session array the way they were added, not like this?

In this particular example, I added `cart_8` last, and as you can see it is second in the list.

Comment: Give each item an order number. Then you can always sort/iterate based on its value.

Comment: why are you using those keys? why not `$cart[4] = 1`? composite keys like that are pointless, especially if you need to extract those "subnumbers" later on.

Comment: What's the point in keeping them in order?

Comment: It's actually a shopping cart, and I want them to show up one after the other in the order they were added.

Answer (score 1):

You must be splicing elements in or sorting the array.  The order of an array is the order in which the elements were were added:

```
$a['cart_9'] = 2;
$a['cart_18'] = 1;
$a['cart_4'] = 1;
$a['cart_8'] = 1;

print_r($a);

Array
(
    [cart_9] => 2
    [cart_18] => 1
    [cart_4] => 1
    [cart_8] => 1
)
```

Even for numerically indexed arrays:

```
$a[9] = 2;
$a[18] = 1;
$a[4] = 1;
$a[8] = 1;

print_r($a);

Array
(
    [9] => 2
    [18] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [8] => 1
)
```

Comment: @BlekStena It might, therefore, be helpful if you could provide the piece of code which processes the session data for us to see if there is perhaps a part which sorts your array for you.

Comment: I add them like this `$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['id']]++;` and it gets sorted by the id automatically